# Swift Async Imageloader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to implement a tableview with cells that display an image. The images will be loaded asynchroniously. For better scrolling I want the request to be canceled if the cell scrolls out of the view.
My code so far works, but I don't know how to detect if the cell is visible or already "scrolled over".

Here's my code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventsTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsTableCell
    var elem : Event = data[indexPath.row] as Event

    cell.headlineLabel.text = elem.getName()
    cell.secondLabel.text = elem.getDescription()

    cell.progressView.setProgress(0.0,animated: true)

    if let image = ImageCache.getImage(elem.getId()) {
        cell.coverImage.image = image
        cell.progressView.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        cell.coverImage.image = UIImage(named: "loading")
        if(elem.getCover() == nil){
            //NOIMAGE
            cell.progressView.removeFromSuperview()
        }else{
            println("start request for" + elem.getName()!)
            cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, elem.getCover()!)
                .progress {
                    (_, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // 6
                        cell.progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead), animated: true)

                        // 7
                        if totalBytesRead == totalBytesExpectedToRead {
                            cell.progressView.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                    if error == nil && cell.coverImage.image != nil {
                        ImageCache.addImage(elem.getId(),image: UIImage(data: data!, scale:1)!)
                        cell.coverImage.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1)
                    }else{

                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

And with the following code I can cancel the request:

```
cell.request!.cancel()
```

I also noticed that the progressView isn't displayed sometimes, or maybe will be deleted from the superview to early, maybe someone can help.

Thanks
Tobias

Comment: Check out this tutorial, towards the end the author goes over how to handle this exact scenario: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are reused by table view for performance reasons. So the same cell could be used a lot of time for different indexPath.

Following line

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventsTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsTableCell
```

creates a new EventsTableCell object only if there is no one to be reused!

So now an `progressView` issue is clear - you remove it from your cell by calling

```
cell.progressView.removeFromSuperview()
```

but you never add it. For example you could add it right after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call and remove later if needed.  I also think in your case it will be better not to remove/add it but hide/show instead:

```
cell.progressView.hidden = false
```

Quite the same for an image request - you can call

```
cell.request?.cancel()
```

just after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

To make your code more obvious you can cancel in [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) method of EventsTableCell but it will have the same effect.

> **prepareForReuse**
>
> Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.

Answer (score 3):

> For better scrolling I want the request to be canceled if the cell scrolls out of the view.

Implement `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and, in it, cancel the download for this row. That is exactly what this delegate method is for!

Comment: Full example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyTableViewController.swift